# How do Hilbert's foundational geometry axioms I,7-8 show that space is three dimensional?

Tags: geometry, axioms

In Hilbert's *Foundations of Geometry* he gives his axioms for geometry. Group I, called the axioms of incidence, details the way points, lines and planes exist.  The last two axioms of the group are

> I, 7.   *If two planes $\alpha$, $\beta$ have a point $A$ in common then they have at least one more point $B$ in common*
>
> I, 8.   *There exists at least four points which do not lie in a plane*

In the next paragraph he explains that "Axiom I, 7 expresses the fact that space has no more than three dimensions, whereas Axiom I, 8 expresses the fact that space has no less than three dimensions." Effectively saying that space has exactly three dimensions.

How do these two axioms intuitively express these two statements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a space with at least four dimensions, you can exhibit two planes which meet at a single  point.  This axiom precludes that from happening.

If every set of four points lies in a plane, then all points lie in a single plane.  This axiom precludes that from happening.

Comment: How can you exhibit two planes that meet at only one point in four or more dimensions.  Do you need to use Cartesian coordinates or is there a synthetic interpretation?

Comment: @BENG Hilbert’s axioms can be shown to be equivalent to real analytic geometry, so both suffice.

Comment: @BENG  I don’t know how one would prove it synthetically off the top of my head, because I do not recall Hilbert defining any notion of “dimension”.  Perhaps he is just rephrasing the axioms as intuition.

Comment: yeh that makes sense that it his explanations are intuitive and in no sense are rigorous statements